# Angular - 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) in sinup activate

Tags: angular, laravel, nginx

I have used Angular-11 for frontend and Laravel-8 for backend in a project.

When user signup, there will be notification to activate.

Laravel:

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
 {   
    return (new MailMessage)
     ->subject('Confirm your account')
     ->line('Thanks for signup! Please before you begin, you must confirm your account.')
     ->action('Confirm Account', url('https://myapp/auth/signup-activate?token='.$notifiable->activation_token))
     ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
  }
```

Angular:

App.routing:

```
 {path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./features/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)},
```

Auth.routing:

```
{
  path: 'signup-activate',
  component: SignupConfirmComponent
}
```

When the user clicks the link in his email notification;

```
https://myapp/auth/signup-activate?token=92KoHrO59b
```

It suppose to take to the signup-activate, but got this error:

> 404 Not Found
> nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

But the route exists.

I observe that it has to do with the production server. For instance, if I type the url below on browser and hit enter key, gives the 404 error"

```
https://myapp/auth
```

But if I put it on routerLink, and click the button, it works.

Also, this works:

```
 <li><a routerLink="/auth/signup" class="dropdown-item"><i class="far fa-user"></i> Signup</a></li>
```

> But if I type the same url and hit enter key, it doesn't work

Note: All these happen on production serve. But everything works fine on local system.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks